# How to parse '' as 0, otherwise parse decimal in TSQL?

Tags: t-sql, casting

I'm inserting a record into a TSQL table which contains a value that could either be a decimal value or an empty string.  How can I parse the empty string as 0, otherwise a decimal?

Sadly, the application I'm interfacing with will not allow a "CASE WHEN" statement.

I've tried:

```
SELECT CONVERT(decimal(15,2),'')
SELECT CAST('' as decimal(15,2))
SELECT CAST(COALESCE('',0.00) as decimal(15,2))
```

Each gives:
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Answer (score 0):

```
select case when your_column = ''
            then 0
            else your_column 
       end as your_column 
from your_table
```

Comment: Unfortunately the application I'm working with doesn't support "case when". Thanks though.